# Citrix receiver strange colors

Tags: display

I have a raspberry PI and installed Citrix Receiver.
For that I used this 
http://rpitc.blogspot.pt/

And it works perfectly on the PI! At 16bits this means gradients get halos and so on.
When I bump it to 32 bits

```
framebuffer_depth=32
```

I get 'orange graphics' I tried increasing the GPU mem, GPU clock.
The same happens to 24 bits.

Does anyone have any idea to solve or at least reduce this problem?

Answer (score 1):

By default the RaspberryPi framebuffer is only 16-bit. So at higher color depths in the software you're probably seeing the effects of some integer wrapping.

You can set the framebuffer depth higher, but it may not work well. According to [this](http://elinux.org/RPiconfig), you can set the Pi to both 24 and 32 bit depths by changing framebuffer_depth in /boot/config.txt. At 24-bit there have apparently been corruption issues reported. 32-bit depth works better, but requires alpha to be disabled by setting framebuffer_ignore_alpha to 1 in config.txt.